# When the field "Topic" are null/empty the Gerrit Trigger event are not called

Tags: regex, jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I'm struggling with an issue with a CI that I configured in `Jenkins` where it should be triggered to each Patchset Created in a specific branch, however it shouldn't be trigger in case the field `Topic` at `Gerrit` is configured as "foo".
So I'm using this `^((?!foo)).*$` regex (negative lookahead) to control it, and it is working properly when the "Topic" are filled with all string different of "foo", however when the developers leave it as empty/null the event trigger is not working.

Comment: if your regexp matches on nothing, then probably a bug - by the way I am the guy who requested this feature back in 2013 https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19019

Comment: It's not clear what "trigger is not working" means... is the job triggering to empty topics or not?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira the job is just triggered when the `Topic` has any string filed different of `foo`. Thus, when the `Topic` is empty/null the job is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following options:

**Jenkins configuration**

1) Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System

2) Go to Global properties > Environment variables

3) Add the a variable:

```
Name = GERRIT_TOPIC
Value = null
```

**Job configuration**

1) Go to the job > Configure

2) Go to Build Environment

3) Click on Inject environment variables to the build process

4) Add the following to the Properties Content field:

```
GERRIT_TOPIC=
```

Comment: I've tried it but unfortunately it didn't work.
It's seems that `Jenkins` just are using the local environment variables after the job was triggered thru a `Gerrit Event`.

Comment: I added one more option, this worked out to me. If it doesn't work to you please add the Gerrit/Jenkins/Gerrittrigger versions you're using.

Comment: I'm using these versions: `Gerrit 2.14.8-89` \ `Jenkins ver. 1.573`, `Gerrittrigger plugin 2.11.1`, `Git Plugin 2.2.5`.

Comment: It worked to me with: Gerrit 2.14.3, Jenkins 2.107.2, GerritTrigger plugin 2.27.5 and Git plugin 2.7.1. I would try to update (at least) the plugins. They're really old.

Comment: you are right, the root case of my issue is related with the version of jenkins that our scm team are using, so yesterday I decided to have my own jenkins master so I instaled the lastest version of it and right now everything goes well.
I really apreciate your help, tnx dude.